# What is --image-project argument of gcloud compute instances create command?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

Please help understand what is **--image-project** argument of the `gcloud compute instances create` command.

Following [Architecting with Google Kubernetes Engine](https://www.coursera.org/learn/foundations-google-kubernetes-engine-gke/home/welcome) in Coursera. There is an instruction to create a VM as below.

It looks to me there is a project which creates and maintains the Debian Linux image for the GCP platform which is to be specified with the **--image-project** argument.

```
gcloud compute instances create $MY_VMNAME \
--machine-type "e2-standard-2" \
--image-project "debian-cloud" \      # <-----
--image-family "debian-9" \
--subnet "default"
```

However, not clear what the documentation means.

- [gcloud compute instances create](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create)

> --image-project=IMAGE_PROJECT
> **The Google Cloud project against which all image and image family references will be resolved**. It is best practice to define image-project. **A full list of available projects can be generated by running gcloud projects list**.

Running the `gcloud projects list` as per the documentation does not show the **"debian-cloud"**. I think it is showing the project which the current GCP account user can access.

```
$ gcloud projects list

PROJECT_ID: cloudshell-images
NAME: Google Cloud Shell
PROJECT_NUMBER: 205372091086

PROJECT_ID: esoteric-quanta-324122
NAME: RMqwiklabs-gcp-02-6dae71c9f143
PROJECT_NUMBER: 313871830131

PROJECT_ID: pso-vmaas-1
NAME: pso-vmaas-1
PROJECT_NUMBER: 687834401499

PROJECT_ID: qwiklabs-gcp-02-d5ed5f282fe4
NAME: qwiklabs-gcp-02-d5ed5f282fe4
PROJECT_NUMBER: 138724239027

PROJECT_ID: qwiklabs-resources
NAME: Qwiklabs Resources
PROJECT_NUMBER: 1030115194620
```

## Question

Is the documentation correct? Does `--image-project` refer to a GCP project which Debian linux people or GCP is managing the Debian VM images for GCP?

Answer (score 2):

There are two types of compute engine VM images according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images):

> - **Public images** are provided and maintained by Google, open source
>   communities, and third-party vendors. By default, all Google Cloud
>   projects have access to these images and can use them to create
>   instances.
> - **Custom images** are available only to your Cloud project. You
>   can create a custom image from boot disks and other images. Then, use
>   the custom image to create an instance.

Some Google managed projects with public images are: `debian-cloud`, `windows-cloud`, `centos-cloud`. In case of using public image you need to set `--image-project` value to public project id.

You can also create "Custom images" in one of your GCP projects. In this case you need to set `--image-project` value to your project id when creating inctance form custom image.

I think you are right, that this paragraph in the documentation looks incorrect, as referred command doesn't list projects with public images:

> --image-project=IMAGE_PROJECT
>
> The Google Cloud project against which all image and image family references will be resolved. It is best
> practice to define image-project. A full list of available projects
> can be generated by running gcloud projects list.

To list available images (public and custom) you can run:

```
gcloud compute images list
```